# jQuery validate - two required fields with one error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I've been trying to use the 'group' option of the [jQuery validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) to validate two select boxes where both are required but only one error message should display:

JavaScript:

```
$('form').validate({
    groups: {
        cardExpiration: 'card_expirationMonth card_expirationYear'
    },
    rules: {
        card_expirationMonth: 'required',
        card_expirationYear: 'required'
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element[0].name === 'card_expirationMonth' || element[0].name === 'card_expirationYear') {
            error.prependTo('form');
        }
    }
});
```

Mark-up:

```
<form method="post" action="/wherever">
    <div class="-field field-expirationMonth">
        <select name="card_expirationMonth" id="card_expirationMonth">
            <option value="">MM</option>
            <option value="01">01</option>
            <option value="02">02</option>
            <option value="03">03</option>
            <option value="04">04</option>
            <option value="etc">Etc</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="-field field-expirationYear">
        <select name="card_expirationYear" id="card_expirationYear">
            <option value="">YY</option>
            <option value="2012">12</option>
            <option value="2013">13</option>
            <option value="2014">14</option>
            <option value="2015">15</option>
            <option value="etc">Etc</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

This seems to group the error messages so there's only ever one visible but it seems to take the approach that only one field in the group is required... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The demo on http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options shows this code:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  groups: {
    username: "fname lname"
  },
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     if (element.attr("name") == "fname" 
                 || element.attr("name") == "lname" )
       error.insertAfter("#lastname");
     else
       error.insertAfter(element);
   },
   debug:true
 })
```

Notice that 'rules' is absent.  Maybe things will shape up if you remove it from your code.

Comment: Yeah I've read the docs - rules is there to define the validation method that should take place on the named elements. (The reason it's not there in the demo is because the rules have been defined in a declarative manner using the class attribute).

Comment: @riscarrott: It's interesting to me that the other samples on the page use "rules" in the validate method options, while this one uses the class attribute.  Have you tried it that way?

Comment: Yeah I've tried it both ways - the others use 'rules' instead of class or meta data usually because they're demonstrating something more specific I believe.

Comment: This plugin is supposed to be the be all and end all but I'm just not impressed!

Comment: @riscarrott: Well, if you're brave/patient enough, you could find the problem in the plugin code, fix it and submit it to the appropriate people.

Comment: Yeah, I'm reading through it now but it's aloooooot of code (>1k lines) - I figured it'd cover everything seeing its size! I've noticed the group option works if you turn off the 'live' keyup and focusin / out events like the demo but I need these. I'm now looking at forgetting about the group option and adding a custom method with $.validator.addMethod... not ideal but I'll drop any code here if I end up with something useable.